# Update data with EF migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I want to update a new column I have created in a table something like this:

```
public partial class PortDealerTokens : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        IEnumerable<DealerAdapter> dealers;

        using (var context = new TestDriveContext())
        {
            dealers = context.Dealers.ToList();

        }

        foreach (var dealer in dealers)
        {
            using (var newContext = new TestDriveContext())
            {
                dealer.Token = < MyFunction >;

                newContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

This code is not working because when I invoke Update-Database there are errors saying Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'. The duplicate key value is (201812180729383_PortDealerTokens.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a better strategy?

Comment: Firing up your context twice in a migration could be an issue. Have you tried moving your foreach loop inside the first using...

Comment: Yes, I'll tried that. Unfortunately without a positive result. I got the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831052/update-data-with-ef-migrations?noredirect=1#comment94621396_53831052

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [override seed method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3)
or by `Sql` method in migration class

```
public partial class PortDealerTokens : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        //Sql script to populate your data   
        Sql("");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

**Update**

However you have new migration or not seed method will run when you run update-database command 
[image]
in this image

1-add-migration 'migration name'-- adding new empty migration

2-update database -- applying this migration then Running Seed method

3-updata database -- No pending explicit migrations then Running Seed method.

Comment: This solution won't work. I can't put this on the Migration Scripts because I have to invoke my method in the Sql statment. Overriding the seed method doesn't work either, because my overridden seed function will not be invoked because I use this in an existing project where migrations already are implemented. Is there another solution?

Comment: however you have new migration or not `seed` method will run ,when you run `update-database` `seed` method will run  after applying new migrations ,if there in no new migration to run seed method will run,
so make sure the method you will invoke  on `seed` method will not corrupt your data

Comment: I've tried that and it worked! But the seed method will always be executed after Update-Database. What I want is that this seed method is executed only once. Is this possible?

Comment: you can use `appsettings` section in web.config

`<add key="ApplySeed" value="true" />` //true or false

protected override void Seed(Data.DBEntities context)
{
    string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplySeed"];
    bool ApplySeed = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
    if(ApplySeed)
    {
        //your code here
    }
}